# jQuery not removing absolute positioned divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which will hide the parent `div` of the link you click on. When the `div`'s are relatively positioned, there is no problem, but when they are absolutely positioned, they won't remove.

The script also saves the state of each element to `localStorage`, and the error only happens the first time you try to close one of the divs. What I mean by this is that, if you show three divs, say div one, two, and three, and then try to close the top most div, it won't close. If you reload the page, and try to close div three, which is on top from before you reloaded the page, it will close.

There's a little bit too much code to post, [so here's the jsFiddle for it](http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/jgctY/1/). But here's the code for posterity:

```
function loadWidgets() {
    $(".base").each(function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var counter = localStorage.getItem("counter-" + id) || 0;
        var active = localStorage.getItem(id + "-active") || "";
        $.each(active.split(" "), function (k, v) {
            var s = v.split(",");
            if (s.length != 2) {
                return;
            }
            var newElement = $("#" + s[0]).clone(true, true);
            newElement.attr("id", s[1]).attr("class", "drag " + id).data("id", id).appendTo("body");
        });
    });
}

function closeWidget() {
    var id = $(this).parent().attr("id").match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    var active = [];
    $($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () {
        active.push(id + "," + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
    active = active.join(" ");
    localStorage.setItem(id + "-active", active);
}

function cloneWidget() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href").match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
    var key = "counter-" + id;
    var counter = localStorage.getItem(key) || 0;
    counter++;
    var newElement = $("#" + id).clone(true, true);
    newElement.attr("id", id + counter).attr("class", "drag " + id).appendTo("body");
    var active = [];
    $($("." + id).not(".base")).each(function () {
        active.push(id + ',' + $(this).attr("id"));
    });
    active = active.join(" ");
    localStorage.setItem(id + "-active", active);
    localStorage.setItem(key, counter);
}
loadWidgets();
$(".nav a").click(cloneWidget);
$(".close").click(closeWidget);​
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="base" id="one" style="background-color:blue">
    <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
    <input class="input" id="test"/>
    <textarea class="textarea" id="test2"></textarea>

</div>
<div class="base" id="two" style="background-color:red">
    <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="base" id="three" style="background-color:green">
    <a class="close" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
<div class="nav">
    <a href="#one">One</a>
    <a href="#two">Two</a>
    <a href="#three">three</a>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) doesn't copy events by default:

> `.clone( [withDataAndEvents] [, deepWithDataAndEvents] )`
>   [...]
>   Normally, any event handlers bound to the original element are not copied to the clone. The optional `withDataAndEvents` parameter allows us to change this behavior, and to instead make copies of all of the event handlers as well, bound to the new copy of the element.

And since you have events bound to things inside what you're cloning, you want `deepWithDataAndEvents` to be true as well:

```
var newElement = $("#" + s[0]).clone(true, true);
```

Corrected fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Jdutt/

Answer (score 1):

You create a new widget but you do not assign an event handler to the *Close* link.

Take the next line and put it **at the end** of the **cloneWidget** function:

```
$("#" + id + counter + " a.close").click(closeWidget);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that add an additional binding to the close links that are already created?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. I fixed it now.

Comment: (1) You want `$("#" + id + counter + " a.close").click(closeWidget);` and (2) you have to do that *after* you've added the clone to the DOM with `appendTo`. `newElement.find('a.close').click(closeWidget)` would be an alternative that will work before `appendTo`.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. And yes, you have to put that sentence after you appended the *Close* link. I made it clear now.